# In Symfony3 I am trying to persist form data to the database, but it doesn't go to the current user's row, instead creates a new entry

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

All fields in the new database row created are null except isActive and workout_choice, which are set to 1 (as they should be, but SHOULD be for the current user--who has a row with id, user info, etc., not for a new user). For some reason, the system isn't picking up the current user who is logged in, but when var_dumping $user, I get the current user's info.

If anyone has any ideas of what I'm missing, it would be much appreciated. Here's my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route ("user/LandingPage", name="user_LandingPage")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function landingPage(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\LandingPageType');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $x = $form->getData();
    $user = $this->getCurrentUser();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->persist($x);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->chartAction();

return $this->render('user/LandingPage.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

}
```

Here's my getCurrentUser function in my DefaultController:

```
    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
        return $userRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->
        getUser()>getId()));
```

And here's my FormType file:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LandingPageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
    $options)
        {
        $builder
           ->add('workoutChoice', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Choose Your Workout',
                'choices' => array(
                'Pyramid Workout Day 1' => 0,
                'Pyramid Workout Day 2' => 1),
                'attr' => array('style' => 'width:200px;',
                )))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(

            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

}
```

And here's my twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<head>

{% block stylesheets %}<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" 
rel="stylesheet" media="screen">{% endblock %}
</head>
<body background="{{ asset('sport-1244925_1920.jpg') }}">

<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<h3>Please choose which workout you wish to do today:</h3>

{{ form_start(form, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'col_size': 'xs' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.workoutChoice) }}
    {{ form_row(form.submit) }}

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

In my entity file:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", length=6, name="workout_choice", 
       nullable=true)
 */
private $workoutChoice;

/**
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getWorkoutChoice()
{
    return $this->workoutChoice;
}

/**
 * @param integer $workoutChoice
 */
public function setWorkoutChoice($workoutChoice)
{
    $this->workoutChoice = $workoutChoice;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your getCurrentUser() function, please?

Comment: public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        $userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
        return $userRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $this->getUser()->getId()));

Comment: Well, you're getting new row in your db, because you're actually persisting new user-entity with `$em->persist($x);` The quickest way to make it work for you `$user->setWorkoutChoice($x->getWorkoutChoice())` and remove  `$em->persist($x);`

Comment: Ok. I guess then that I don't understand why it is a new entity since in the var_dump it gives me the current user. Do you know the remedy?

Comment: The answer below says it all. I was getting the user from getCurrentUser, but it just wasn't persisting to the db because it wasn't in the createForm signature-- wanna those doh! moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the current user to your form. As in:

```
$user = $this->getCurrentUser();
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\LandingPageType', $user);
```

Also, you can get the current user in Symfony3 controllers with a simple:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Comment: Hey Mr. Olivieri! That was it! Thank you. :)

Comment: You're quite welcome. I've done this a couple times myself, that's how I know. Ha ha.

Comment: LOL. Cheers! :)